# Excel Application Match with 1904 Date system

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a piece of code that will search for a specific date in a spreadsheet, it works fine using the 1900 date system, but gets a Type Mismatch 13 error when i try to use the 1904 date system. Both workbooks are set to the 1904 date system.

```
Dim fDate As Date
Dim rw As Long
Dim name As String
Dim srchRange As Range
Dim book2name As String, book2 As Workbook

book2name = "Master_Sheet.xlsm"   ' name of Source File
Set book2 = Workbooks(book2name)
name = "SM"

fDate = GetWeekStartDate(Range("C12"))
Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(name).Range("B:B")    ' Search Range

If Application.CountIf(srchRange, fDate) Then
    rw = Application.Match(CLng(fDate), srchRange, 0)
Else
    MsgBox Format(fDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " not found."
End If

Function GetWeekStartDate(ByVal strdate, Optional ByVal lngStartDay As Long = 2) As String
GetWeekStartDate = DateAdd("d", _
                   -Weekday(CDate(strdate), lngStartDay) + 1, CDate(strdate))
End Function
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: rw = Application.Match(CLng(fDate), srchRange, 0)

Comment: You have to correct for the true underlying value: `rw = Application.Match(CLng(fDate) - 1462, srchRange, 0)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine.

Comment: @Rory - Given that there is no readily searchable answer to adapting a 1904 date to a VBA `Application.Match`, maybe you could contribute your solution as an answer (or Community Wiki if you absolutely, positively do not want the rep).

Answer (score 0):

Because of the 1904 date system, the underlying value of the cells is not the same as it would be with the 1900 date system, even though the dates appear the same. That means that you need to offset the value by 1462 for `Match` to find it:

```
rw = Application.Match(CLng(fDate) - 1462, srchRange, 0)
```

Comment: Still having a couple problems with this, the offset value works fine if the workbook i'm pulling from is in the 1904 date system and the active workbook is in the 1900 system. But as i need to make use of negative time values both workbooks need to be in the 1904 date system, with the offset my code does not find the date i'm looking for. And without the offset i'm getting Error 13 Type Mismatch. Am i missing something?

Comment: I'm confused. The Type Mismatch occurs *because* the data can't be found (and you're trying to assign an error value to a `Long` variable), so what do you mean by "with the offset my code does not find the date i'm looking for"

Comment: Lets say i'm looking for today's date. With both workbooks as 1904 system, with the offset in place the code executes but returns `MsgBox Format(fDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " not found."` . If i remove the offset i get the type mismatch. I'm guessing its something wrong with `If Application.CountIf(srchRange, fDate) Then` but i'm not sure of a solution.

Comment: What is the value of `fDate`?

Comment: fdate is the date of week beginning, `fDate = GetWeekStartDate(Range("C12"))` i have included the function in my original question. It will find the week beginning date from the date value in C12

Comment: I mean what is its actual value when the code is not working? I can see how it's calculated (though I don't know why your function returns a string)

Comment: The value of fdate when the code is not working is 16/11/2015

Comment: I can't replicate that. If both books are 1904 system, the `Countif` works fine without offsetting and the `Match` works fine with the offset.